# Sap UI5 dynamic binding on table depending on reference field

Tags: sapui5

[List items with toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUtzc.png)

Hi experts, I am trying to come up with an approval app but not in a master-detail approach. As shown above, i want it to be in a table format with 2 tabs; 1 tab for the list of for approval and 1 other tab for the approved items.

For instance I have the following json data, is it possible to filter the model based on "status" and dynamically bind the filtered result to 1 table only, but will show result based on clicked tab: For Approval tab and Approved tab:

```
"QNPResult": [
        {
            "QNPNo": "QNP01",
            "MatDesc": "BROWN SUGAR",
            "PY": "38.46",
            "ACT": "35.17",
            "BP": "38.7",
            "OpenPOBal": "33.44",
            "CurrentPrice": "KG",
            "InvStock": "29.04",
            "InvMonth": "Feb 2018",
            "RecoVol": "700,000",
            "BookUntil": "Book until March 2018",
            "PriceOutlook": "Decreasing due to enough supply driven by crop season",
            "Status": "1"
        },
        {
            "QNPNo": "QNP02",
            "MatDesc": "WHITE SUGAR",
            "PY": "39.46",
            "ACT": "41.17",
            "BP": "48.7",
            "OpenPOBal": "43.44",
            "CurrentPrice": "KG",
            "InvStock": "49.04",
            "InvMonth": "March 2018",
            "RecoVol": "800,000",
            "BookUntil": "Book until March 2019",
            "PriceOutlook": "Decreasing due to enough supply driven by crop season",
            "Status": "1"
        },
        {
            "QNPNo": "QNP03",
            "MatDesc": "SUGAR",
            "PY": "69.46",
            "ACT": "71.17",
            "BP": "88.7",
            "OpenPOBal": "93.44",
            "CurrentPrice": "KG",
            "InvStock": "19.04",
            "InvMonth": "March 2019",
            "RecoVol": "100,000",
            "BookUntil": "Book until March 2020",
            "PriceOutlook": "Decreasing due to enough supply driven by crop season",
            "Status": "2"
        }
    ],
```

Let me know also if there are better way of achieving the design I want. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that JSON data you are showing is local data or coming from an oData service?

Comment: Hi Santhosh, this are just mockdata coming from a local data(json file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image you linked, and the behaviour you described I suggest you to use this approach from SAPUI5 SDK - Demo Kit: [Icon Tab Bar - Filter](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBar/code/IconTabBar.controller.js)

Take a look at the Controller, the `handleIconTabBarSelect` method does the trick: based on the selected tab it filters the table's binding `oBinding.filter(aFilters);` with different set of `sap/ui/model/Filter` instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
var status1 = [];
var status2 = [];
for(var i = 0; i<QNPResult.length; i++){
   if(QNPResult[i].Status === "1"){
      status1.push(QNPResult[i]);
   }else{
      status2.push(QNPResult[i])
   } 
}
```

> Set those arrays to the dependent table model.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. and here is one
http://jsbin.com/yavuhay/edit?js,output

```
sap.ui.jsview("myView.Template", {
  getControllerName: function() {
    return "myView.Template";
  },
  createContent: function(oController) {
    function createList(filter) {
      return new sap.m.List({
        columns: [
          new sap.m.Column({
            header:new sap.m.Text({
              text:"QNPNo"
            })
          }),
          new sap.m.Column({
            header:new sap.m.Text({
              text:"Status"
            })
          })
        ],
        items: {
          path: '/QNPResult',
          template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [
              new sap.m.Text({
                text: '{QNPNo}'
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text: '{Status}'
              })
            ]
          }),
          filters: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Status", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, filter)]
        }
      })
    }
    return new sap.m.VBox({
      items: [
        sap.m.IconTabBar({
          items:[
            new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
              icon: "sap-icon://approvals",
              content: [ 
                new createList("1")
              ]
            }),
            new sap.m.IconTabFilter("Step3", {
              icon: "sap-icon://accept",
              content: [
                new createList("2")
              ]
            })
          ]
        })
      ]
    });
  }
});

sap.ui.define([
  'jquery.sap.global',
  'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
  'sap/ui/model/Filter',
  'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
], function(jQuery, Controller, Filter, JSONModel) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
    onInit: function(oEvent) {
      this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
        "QNPResult": [
          {
            "QNPNo": "QNP01",
            "MatDesc": "BROWN SUGAR",
            "PY": "38.46",
            "ACT": "35.17",
            "BP": "38.7",
            "OpenPOBal": "33.44",
            "CurrentPrice": "KG",
            "InvStock": "29.04",
            "InvMonth": "Feb 2018",
            "RecoVol": "700,000",
            "BookUntil": "Book until March 2018",
            "PriceOutlook": "Decreasing due to enough supply driven by crop season",
            "Status": "1"
          },
          {
            "QNPNo": "QNP02",
            "MatDesc": "WHITE SUGAR",
            "PY": "39.46",
            "ACT": "41.17",
            "BP": "48.7",
            "OpenPOBal": "43.44",
            "CurrentPrice": "KG",
            "InvStock": "49.04",
            "InvMonth": "March 2018",
            "RecoVol": "800,000",
            "BookUntil": "Book until March 2019",
            "PriceOutlook": "Decreasing due to enough supply driven by crop season",
            "Status": "1"
          },
          {
            "QNPNo": "QNP03",
            "MatDesc": "SUGAR",
            "PY": "69.46",
            "ACT": "71.17",
            "BP": "88.7",
            "OpenPOBal": "93.44",
            "CurrentPrice": "KG",
            "InvStock": "19.04",
            "InvMonth": "March 2019",
            "RecoVol": "100,000",
            "BookUntil": "Book until March 2020",
            "PriceOutlook": "Decreasing due to enough supply driven by crop season",
            "Status": "2"
          }
        ]
      }))
    }
  });
});


var view = sap.ui.view({
  type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
  viewName: "myView.Template"
});
view.placeAt("content");
```